# How to convert array from lineal to multidimensional in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following input array:

```
$arr =  [
  "quote_id" => "1",
  "ONE" => "2018-03-12",
  "TWO" => "2018-02-12",
  "THREE" => "2018-01-12",
  "FOUR" => "2017-12-12"
];
```

and I need to transform to the following output:

```
 [
  "quote_id" => "1",
  "ONE" => "2018-03-12"
 ],
 [
  "quote_id" => "1",
  "TWO" => "2018-02-12"
 ],
 [
  "quote_id" => "1",
  "THREE" => "2018-01-12"
 ],
 [
  "quote_id" => "1",
  "FOUR" => "2017-12-12"
 ]
```

The idea is to insert a record in the DB per each `COLUMN` (ONE, TWO, ...) so I end up with:

```
INSERT INTO table id=1, value="2018-03-12"
INSERT INTO table id=1, value="2018-02-12"
INSERT INTO table id=1, value="2018-01-12"
INSERT INTO table id=1, value="2017-12-12"
```

Can I get some help?

Comment: have you tried looping in from your array and from that creating the multidimensional array based on what you want it?

Comment: Is `"quote_id"` always the first item?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aslong as quote_id is the key that you want inserted every time

```
foreach ($arr  as $key => $value) {
     if($key != "quote_id")
     {
       /* insert $arr["quote_id"], $value */
     }
}
```